# IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to implement his Java code with Hibernate in order to make SQL queries:

```
public List<AttendeeModel> getListOfCds(int firstRow, int rowCount) {
        List<AttendeeModel> cdList = null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AttendeeModel.class);
            criteria.setFirstResult(firstRow);
            criteria.setMaxResults(rowCount);
            if (criteria != null) {
                cdList = (List<AttendeeModel>) criteria.list();
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return cdList;
    }

    public int countRows() {
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AttendeeModel.class);
            if (criteria != null) {
                return criteria.list().size();
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: At which statement is the exception thrown ?

Comment: ... in `countRows()` the transaction stays open if `criteria != null`, is that intended ?

Comment: I copied the code from a tutorial. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is unclear where `session` is decleared and how it is populated. Given that this is done somehow correctly, I suspect that missing transaction commit/rollback before return in countRow leads to the exception, try:

```
public int countRows() {
    int size = 0;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AttendeeModel.class);
        if (criteria != null) {
            size = criteria.list().size();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work by just using `@PersistenceContext`, we need to set PersistenceContextType also which is by default `TRANSACTION`, but in this case when multiple threads try to use same singleton instance of `EntityManager`, we need to set it to `EXTENDED` like this -

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and it worked. I got this issue when i was trying to execute a db query in one of my schedulars.